# Google Service Account "NOT_ADS_USER"

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-cloud-iam

I'm attempting to use the Google Ads API Client Library for PHP with a Service Account json.

Inviting the Service Account to Google Ads account has status of "Awaiting response" - but I cannot login to the Service Account to accept the invite.

Here is the code being used:

```
<?php
// Include the Google Ads API PHP client library
require_once 'googleads_google-ads-php/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V13\GoogleAdsClientBuilder;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V13\GoogleAdsServerStreamDecorator;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Util\V13\ResourceNames;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V13\Services\GoogleAdsQuery;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

$developerToken = "developerToken";
$jsonKeyFilePath = "json_key.json";
$customerId = "CustomerId";

// Set up authentication using a service account JSON file
$googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
    ->withDeveloperToken($developerToken)
->withOAuth2Credential((new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
    ->withJsonKeyFilePath($jsonKeyFilePath)
    ->withScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'])
    ->build())
    ->build();


// Define the query to retrieve data from the age_range_view
$query = "SELECT segments.date, segments.device, metrics.clicks, ad_group_criterion.criterion_id, ad_group_criterion.display_name
          FROM age_range_view
          LIMIT 1000";

try {
    // Execute the query and get the results
    $response = $googleAdsClient->getGoogleAdsServiceClient()->search($customerId, $query);

    // Loop through the rows of data and extract the desired values
    foreach ($response->iterateAllElements() as $googleAdsRow) {
        $date = $googleAdsRow->getSegments()->getDate()->getValue();
        $device = $googleAdsRow->getSegments()->getDevice()->getValue();
        $clicks = $googleAdsRow->getMetrics()->getClicks()->getValue();
        $criterionId = $googleAdsRow->getAdGroupCriterion()->getCriterionId()->getValue();
        $displayName = $googleAdsRow->getAdGroupCriterion()->getDisplayName()->getValue();
        
        // Print the extracted values to the console
        printf("Date: %s | Device: %s | Clicks: %d | Criterion ID: %d | Display Name: %s\n",
            $date,
            $device,
            $clicks,
            $criterionId,
            $displayName
        );
    }
} catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
    printf("Request with ID '%s' has failed.%sGoogle Ads failure details:%s",
        $googleAdsException->getRequestId(),
        PHP_EOL,
        PHP_EOL
    );
    foreach ($googleAdsException->getGoogleAdsFailure()->getErrors() as $error) {
        /** @var GoogleAdsError $error */
        printf("\t%s: %s%s",
            $error->getErrorCode()->getErrorCode(),
            $error->getMessage(),
            PHP_EOL
        );
    }
} catch (ApiException $apiException) {
    printf("ApiException was thrown with message '%s'.%s",
        $apiException->getMessage(),
        PHP_EOL
    );
}
?>
```

Here is the error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: {
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https:\/\/developers.google.com\/identity\/sign-in\/web\/devconsole-project.",
    "code": 16,
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com\/google.ads.googleads.v13.errors.GoogleAdsFailure",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "errorCode": {
                        "authenticationError": "NOT_ADS_USER"
                    },
                    "message": "User in the cookie is not a valid Ads user."
                }
            ],
            "requestId": "requestId"
        }
    ]
}

  thrown in /data_import/googleads_google-ads-php/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php on line 267
```

I attempted to try adding ->withImpersonatedEmail($impersonatedEmail) to the authentication request with an account on the same project that has access to the Google Ads accounts but that did not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Keep in mind you can only use service accounts with the Ads API if you have a [Google Workspace domain](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts#prerequisites). If you do, please disregard this comment :)

Comment: The service account that you created needs to be granted domain wide delegation access by a super administrator for the domain. [link](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/php/oauth-service#create_oauth2_credentials)